# How to go to layer of currently selected object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Say there are hundreds of unnamed layers in an Illustrator artboard. How do you just click one of those objects and reveal what layer it is on? And change to that layer?

Comment: If you click an object on the artboard, the layer it is on is highlighted in the Layer's Panel by a small square on the right side of the layer name.

Answer (score 27):

Select the object. Open the panel menu of the Layers panel:
[image]
Click `Locate Object`:
[image]

To create a keyboard shortcut for this function you can [record an action](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html) and assign a keyboard shortcut to that action.

Comment: Here's a useful tip for mapping this function to a hotkey: https://www.quora.com/Can-you-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-the-Locate-Object-command-in-the-Layers-pallette-of-Adobe-Illustrator